# How to compute the effect size for Friedman's test using sas?

Tags: sas

I was looking for a way to compute the effect size for Friedman's test using `sas`, but could not find any reference. I wanted to see if there is any difference between the groups and what its size was.

Here is my code:

```
proc freq data=mydata;
  tables id*b*y / cmh2 scores=rank noprint;
run;
```

These are the results:

```
The FREQ Procedure  
Summary Statistics for b by y
Controlling for id
Cochran-Mantel-Haenszel Statistics (Based on Rank Scores)

Statistic   Alternative Hypothesis  DF  Value       Prob
1           Nonzero Correlation     1   230.7145    <.0001
2           Row Mean Scores Differ  1   230.7145    <.0001
```

This question is correlated with [the one posted on Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/213934/how-to-compute-effect-size-for-friedmans-test), that is concerned with the general statistical formula to compute the effect size for Friedman's test. Here, I would like to find out how to get the effect size in `sas`.